# How to deal with Foreign key relationships Entity Framework MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public class UserCommentry
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AccountID")]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public virtual Account account { get; set; }
    public Int64 TransferID { get; set; }
}
```

Primary key Field

```
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int code{ get; set; }
    public Int64 TransferID { get; set; }
```

**Error:**

> The property 'AccountID' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type.

Comment: You've put the `ForeignKey` attribute on the wrong place. Just move it right above the `account` property.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it's because navigarion property should be of type you want it to point to. 
If I wanted to create a relationship with an account, I would do it this way:

```
public class UserCommentry
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Account Account{ get; set; }
        public virtual Account account { get; set; }

        public Int64 TransferID { get; set; }
    }
```

And then let context know about it using OnModelCreating. You can read more here http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx